# What is the difference between the words petere and interrogare?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-comparison

I was trying to say something around the lines of

> what more to ask

which it's kind of an idiom which I think it means something around the lines of "I don't need to ask for anything else"?

I think you could say something like

> quid plus petere/interrogare?

not sure if this would achieve it but also not sure which word to use for saying "to ask" in Latin.

I was inclining more towards *petere* since in Spanish you would say

> que mas pedir

instead of saying

> que mas preguntar

which is the literal translation of English but means different in Spanish.

Comment: In English "ask" means both "request" (pedir) and "inquire" (preguntar) -- which meaning do you have in mind?

Comment: request probably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "ask" in your English example is used figuratively (metonymically) for "want, wish for, desire". Neither *petere* nor *interrogāre* have this meaning:

- **petere** means "to act in order to attain; to go for, strive for, seek, to ask for as a service etc.", and is therefore used not with questions but with things. The Spanish verb has had a few shifts of meaning since then, although it's still rather close.
- **interrogāre** means "to ask back and forth, to question, cross-examine etc.", but also "to put as a question, especially a yes-no one; to ask for information". In the latter sense it's synonymous with **percontārī (percūnctārī)**, which gave Sp. *preguntar*.

The best option to express your meaning is **optāre**:

- ***quid amplius optēs? numquid est quod optēs ultrā?***

You can also use **dēsīderāre** (in the form *dēsīderēs*), which is about abstract wishes as opposed to concrete desires. I don't think however that **velle** (*velīs*) "to want" will work: you want to express the generic second person ("one"), but it sounds like a polite direct question ("you who I'm talking to") due to the frequency of such use.

It's possible to use **petere** (*petās*), but only when implying an action directed at attaining the desired object. Similar to this **quaerere** (*quaerās*) "to search for". Another option is **requīrere** (*requīrās*) "to look for, want for", especially when meaning "to lack, need", but I think it would be used primarily to express irritation ("what more can you possibly want (from somebody)?").

Note that it's not possible to use the infinitive as you did in the generic meaning "anyone can" - you can use either the second person subjunctive, or include the verb **posse** in the 2p. subj. form *possīs* (as a rhetorical question) or simply as *potest* with the other verb passive, expressing generic possibility:

- ***quid amplius optāre possīs? nihil ultrā est quod optārī potest***