# Translate "Asking for a friend" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

A modern antiphrasis in English is the phrase, "asking for a friend". It's normally used when a person wants to know something but humorously states that they're asking on behalf of someone else.

What would be the simplest way to express this in Latin?

My first thought is simply:

> Pro amico rogo.

Would another verb be a better choice, like *quaerere*?

Comment: Are you asking this question for a friend?

Comment: How did you know?

Answer (score 6):

- Your choice of preposition is good ('instead of, on behalf of'), but *rogāre* fundamentally means 'to ask for something to be done', and hence 'to approach with a request; to solicit, proposition', especially common in the political sphere, e.g. *Senātus populum/lēgem rogat* means 'the Senate is asking (the people's) assent for the law to be passed'; or as a supplicant, [*prō vītā rogāre*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1014/3/5/8908-8916#5) 'to ask for one's life to be spared' - notice how even the juxtaposed *prō rēpūblicā* has the same meaning. Accordingly, *prō aliquō rogāre* will be understood as 'to approach with a request on behalf of somebody else' with contextual ellipsis; for instance, [here](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1348/1/46/881-891#46) *prō quōdam tribūtāriō rogāre* refers to a request for a *cīvitās* 'citizenship'.
- As a literal translation, I think the verb we're looking for is ***scīscitārī*** 'to request information, to want to know, to be curious', so *prō amīcō scīscitor.* No other verb seems to be as fitting - even the otherwise similar *percontārī* is concerned with the semantic role of Patient ('I'm querying you so that my friend doesn't have to').
- Perhaps a better option is to flip this around and say ***amīcus interrogat, quaerit, scīscitātur.*** It implies and contrasts with the excusing *nōn ego*; as well, it sounds less cryptic, more direct, more Latin. The literal option above cannot really imply a self-distancing excuse, as the English 'asking for myself' would correspond to the benefactive Dative *mihi*, and not to *prō mē*.
- But the most idiomatic way to offer an excuse (not necessarily humorous) is using the expression ***alicuijus causā.*** It's used in precisely this way [in Cicero's *De Oratore,*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/37/10/2017-2029#10) where the speaker (a top jurist and Cicero's prof) replies to another's embarrassed suggestion that what they're about to discuss will seem too trivial and obvious to him. Notice how the use of generic *volēbam* removes the need for a more specific verb:

  > Ego mehercule, inquit Mūcius, anteā **vestrā** magis hoc **causā** volēbam quam meā ('Oh bloody hell, I wanted to hear [= was asking] this before not so much for myself but for the sake of you two, said Mucius').
- So in the end I would suggest ***amīcī** enim **causā volō*** (or else *scīscitor*).

---

Related Q: [What is the difference between the words petere and interrogare?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17592/)

Comment: Cicero's "Orator" & "de Oratore" are two different works. Are you aware of this?

Comment: @tony Nope, I wasn't - thanks!